# Composite key in Dictionary; override GetHashCode(), Equals etc or use structs?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, struct, value-type

I have quite a few dictionaries where the key is a composite of several different values (mostly strings and integers). Do I implement these keys as classes (and override `GetHashCode()`, `Equals()` etc) or do I use `struct` instead?

ReSharper makes it easy to do the overriding, but the code looks horrible. Are there any performance implications of using a struct instead?

Comment: Whichever you choose - the key point here is to treat the data as immutable once you have used it as a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only problem is defining equality for the use in a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` then another path you may choose is implementing an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.  This can be manually passed to the dictionary constructor and take care of equality comparisons for the `TKey` value without modification to the key type.

If you have the more general problem of defining equality for your composite values then I would focus on making the composite value natively support equality.  Yes, defining the full set of methods necessary for equality is a pain but it's mostly boiler plate code.  Getting it right is more important than whether or not the boiler plate code looks messy.

Comment: What I don't like is exactly that "getting it right" can be quite tricky. As an example, if I need to add a new field to the key it is extremely important that I remember to also add the field to the equality comparer/hash code etc. It might be ok as long as I'm the only one doing these things, but I won't be for long..

Comment: @andlju, I agree getting in right is tedious and yes it requires a bit of rigor when updating a type.  But I find that to be poor justification for not implementing equality.  **Any** modification of a type requires you to think carefully about the contracts it holds and to do you best to maintain them.  Equality is not unique in this aspect.

Comment: Yeah, true. So that kind of answers the question about why I still could use a class. But I'm still curious about why I should not use structs? What's the case against them?

Comment: @andlju, I'd go more what's the case for them?  In general I avoid structs unless I have a compelling reason to use them.  Yes it will implement a functional equality mechanism for structs containing otherwise comparable fields.  But the implementation leaves a lot to be desired.  For example it does not override ==, !=, or implement `IEquatable<T>`.  The last is one of the worst because it forces every comparison to include a boxing operation.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually say that for any struct one should always manually code an override of `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` along with implementing `IEquatable<T>`, if it's at all likely that it could be used by someone as a key, so I certainly wouldn't use it just to avoid doing so.

As well as requiring boxing, the default implementation is rather slow as it uses reflection to examine the fields. There are also a bug in at least some framework versions (the implementation quite wisely optimises as a binary compare when doing so will give the correct results, but unfortunately mis-judges when this is the case, and hence two structs containing equivalent `decimal` fields may be considered unequal).

When a quick composite is needed that doesn't really have any meaning to the system besides being a composite key, I'd recommend using `Tuple`. `Tuple.Create()` makes it easy to compose them, and the overrides for `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` are pretty reasonable.

In some cases it can also be suitable to use anonymous classes as keys (only within the context of a given method of course), and here the overrides for `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` are pretty reasonable too.

Comment: Other than exploiting the struct-compare behavior, what ways exist for checking whether instances of `double`, `float`, or `Decimal` are equivalent (positive and negative zero are not equivalent, nor is 1.0m equivalent to 1.00m)?

Comment: @supercat It is and it isn't. The precision isn't fully exposed, but it does affect some results and is affected by constructor choice. I really wish it were more fully one or the other. Still, the behaviour within a default struct containing a decimal matches neither == nor Equals for the decimal, which is not exactly intuitive.

Comment: IMHO, the problem is that Microsoft used sloppy semantics for those overrides of `Object.Equals`; IMHO, 1.0m and 1.00m are no more alike than "cat" and "CAT".  It's certainly useful to have a comparer available that regards them as equal, but a type-agnostic comparison should be pessimistic and regard things as unequal if there's any reason why one object should not be substitutable for the other.  Given such a definition for `Object.Equals`, one may define a safe type-agnostic interning class (though such a class would be enhanced if an object could indicate...

Comment: ...whether there might conceivably exist any other object to which it would compare equal; if an object returns `false` to such a query, an interning class could ignore it).  Interning may improve the performance of immutable types, since `X.Equals(Y)` will be much faster when `X` and `Y` refer to the same object, than when they refer to e.g. completely separate 1,000,000-node immutable trees which contain the same data.  Interning, though, requires that things are only reported as equal when they are absolutely and unambiguously equivalent.

Comment: @supercat Agreed. I'd 100% see their point if they normalised both to 1.0m (or 1m, for that matter). I'd 100% see their point if they exposed a Precision property. In-between though... I do though have a generic interning class that lets you define what equivalence is used (https://github.com/hackcraft/Ariadne/blob/master/ThreadSafeAtomizer.cs). Interning doesn't require unambiguous equivalence, just that you'll never use the pool when you need a narrower equivalence. Unambiguous equivalence is necessary for *general* interning, so that no such narrower equivalence is possible.

Comment: While it would be reasonable in some cases to require a custom comparer to maximize interning performance (in cases where there may be many items that differ only in unimportant ways), I dislike the notion of requiring a custom comparer for *correctness* when designing something like an `InterningImmutableArray<T>`.  BTW, have you given any thought to the design of a weak interning array?  IMHO, Microsoft should have included one, since it would be a great asset when using immutable types.

Comment: @supercat I have, for precisely that reason. The thread-safety of that class though depends on there being strict rules on how a value may be transitioned from empty slot -> stored value -> tombstone as a generalisation of the algorithm described at https://github.com/hackcraft/Ariadne/wiki/Implementing-a-Lock-Free-Hash-Based-Dictionary-in-.NET-and-Mono and weak-references having their own transition would complicate that considerably. (Incidentally, I don't require a custom comparer, I just allow for one, default works fine).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15872/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-supercat)

Answer (score 0):

To create such a composite class, the recommended technique is to inherit from `Tuple<int, string, ...>`.

This way, you don't have to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` yourself, the base class does it for you.

You can easily provide meaningful get accessors for each fields.

```
public class CompositeKey : Tuple<string, int>
{
    public CompositeKey(string name, int age)
        : base(name, age)
    {
    }
    public string Name { get { return Item1; } }
    public int Age { get { return Item2; } }
}
```

This also enforces immutability, which is appropriate for dictionary keys.

As for performance, the builtin Tuples are quite fast. I found custom structs can be faster, though if you really need every extra bit of performance, the best is to encode directly your key data into an int or long.

Comment: If you define a struct, the system will implement an `Equals` method which calls `Equals` on its members, along with a compatible (though probably feeble) `GetHashCode` method.  If you need some other meaning for equality, you can override that with your own behavior.  If, however, you use `Tuple`, I don't think there's any nice way to adjust the meaning of equality.  As for enforcing immutability, the fields of a struct stored within a `Dictionary` can only be changed by rewriting the appropriate `Dictionary` item, so any structs, mutable or not, which base equality on their fields are fine.

Comment: Sure, structs work too, and their mutability is not a problem in dictionaries. But they often aren't worth the cost: in C# structs have a surprising behavior when you don't notice you are dealing with a struct. With Tuples, adjusting the meaning of equality is done by simply choosing the generic argument types, it is good enough when aggregating a bunch of value types.

Comment: I find the behavior of exposed-field structures a lot more predictable than that of classes; if one has e.g. a `List<ExposedFieldStructType>` and wants element 1 to be just like element 0 except for the `X` value, one can use `var temp = myList[0]; temp.X = 3; myList[1] = temp;`.  That will work for all structs with an exposed `int` field `X`.  With classes, however, there are many different patterns one might have to use, depending upon circumstances, to achieve that effect.

Comment: Of course with non-value types you have to be more explicit about the copy/creation of a new instance, but that's not necessarily a bad thing. When creating a key for a dictionary, you typically don't need mutability, and if the class ensures immutability like in my CompositeKey exemple, the behavior is very predictable (as expected from just 10 lines of code).

Comment: Immutable classes have predictable behavior; the difficulty with them is that there's no general pattern to create an instance which is like some other instance with the exception of some specific properties.  In some cases, such operations are seldom needed, but consider a `PhoneNumber` type with traits including `AreaCode`, `Exchange`, `MainNumber`.  If needs to change the `AreaCode` of a `PhoneNumber` from `708` to `847`, without affecting anything else how should one do it?  Saying `it=new PhoneNumber("847", it.AreaCode, it.MainNumber);` may lose information in `it.Extension`.

Comment: Yes, when there are many fields, it is bothersome to create a clone with just one modified field. I think there actually is a pattern for that: a 'Builder' class that has mutable fields, i.e. `myList[1] = new Builder(myList[0]) { X = 3 }.ToImmutable()`. However, here in the context of a "key" class for a dictionary, I think you will mostly be creating new instances directly from the values, so this is probably not needed.